# What happens to the brain during sleep versus unconsciousness?

Tags: human-biology, brain

How does being unconsciousness differ from being asleep and whether it causes breaks in consciousness?

Comment: I'd recommend you to formulate the question on the basis of the mechanisms stopping the brain to control the body during dreams.

Comment: sounds like a great question for an anesthesiologist